# php-fpm isn't installing correctly

Tags: apt, software-installation, php-fpm

I am trying to install `php5-mcrypt`, and when I do, I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-mcrypt is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up php5-fpm (5.6.11+dfsg-1ubuntu3.1) ...
insserv: script php5-fpm: service php-fpm already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package php5-fpm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-fpm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I can not figure out what is causing this. I have tried uninstalling `php5-fpm`:

```
sudo apt-get purge php5-fpm
```

Then installing it again and the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had php7-fpm installed, and in my `/etc/init.d` directory there was a file called `php7-fpm` it seems like removing that fixed the issue.

After removing I was able to install `php5-fpm` without getting that error.